# Не могу зайти в интернет с Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian

В общем прошу относиться к моему вопросу с снисхождениями ибо я не программист (и не когда, не был отличником).

В общем у меня есть аппарат в котором установлен Linux Debian 9.Эта операционная система  специфична и собрана под аппарат к примеру в ней нету графического интерфейса X11.

Сама система прекрасно работает по SSH протоколу, и в директории `/etc/` есть папка `/etc/network` и документ `networks`
заполнен как положено (сравнивал с ресбианом из которого я пишу сей вопрос в интернет ) в файле `/ect/resolv.conf` всё так же повторяется. Но когда в командной строке ввожу `ping www.ru` то он мне выдаёт `ping: www.ru: Temporary failure in name resolution`

**Суть вопроса: Не могу понять каких утилит не хватает.** *Если не в лень, как установить :3* Как вы догадываетесь команда `sudo apt-get имя_утилиты` не работает, и по этому стандартные интернетошные предложение просто не отрабатывают.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот дополнил :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот вызвал `ip addr`, `dhclient eth0`, `ping 8.8.8.8`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот вызвал из расбери она на том же проводе `ip addr`, `dhclient eth0`, `ping 8.8.8.8`

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:5b:bb:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.8.166/24 brd 172.16.8.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3ce0:5e8:71c9:b5ec/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:0e:ee:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dhclient eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=2.33 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=119 time=2.19 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 time=2.29 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=119 time=2.19 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=119 time=2.20 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=119 time=2.12 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=119 time=2.19 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=119 time=2.17 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=119 time=2.21 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=119 time=2.22 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=11 ttl=119 time=2.22 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=12 ttl=119 time=2.17 ms
^Z
[6]+  Остановлен    ping 8.8.8.8
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

общаюсь с аппаратом с помощью COM порта .

---

когда на расбери ввожу `ifconfig`

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.8.166  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.8.255
        inet6 fe80::3ce0:5e8:71c9:b5ec  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:5b:bb:57  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 156437  bytes 107321282 (102.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1327  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 53377  bytes 6674202 (6.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2  bytes 78 (78.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2  bytes 78 (78.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:0e:ee:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

когда на аппарате ввожу `ifconfig`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> ifconfig или ip a пропишите и сравните реквизиты с теми, что
>   показывает "винда" когда кабелёк перетыкаете. - @nobody

вот винда 7

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот дебиан 9

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88359/discussion-on-question-by-timob256-------debian-9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@andreymal спасибо большое :3  Заработало !!!!

Воспользовался вашим предложением

> Воспользуйтесь `ip addr flush dev eth0`, следующая команда `dhclient`  следующая команда `ping www.ru`

Я воспользовался этими командами и они сработали. Хотя честно хочу сказать суть команды `ip addr flush dev eth0`

- `ip addr` показывает мой айпи (команду отображения частного
  IP-адреса)
- `flush` - торрент-клиент в линуксе ????
- `dev` - обозначение фаловой системмы.
- `eth0` - инициализированное соединение интернет соединения.

По сути команда выполняет привязку айпи адреса этого компьютера с инициализированным интернет соединением через торрент-клиент (по сути "торент-клиент" встроенная в линукс, утилита).

Вот картинки подтверждающие мои действия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сейчас команда `ping www.ru` не сработает её лучше заменить на `ping www.ya.ru`